# node mysql query with process.nextTick

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Here is my simplified problem:

I want to separate out my database functions to a different file. It is not working (I have to use `process.nextTick()`)

```
var db = require('./db/db_functions');

process.nextTick(function() {
    var rows = db.selectUserByEmail('levon');
    if (rows.length) { ... }
});

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
//    at /Users/Test/app.js:38:13
//    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
//    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
//    at startup (node.js:119:16)
//    at node.js:929:3
```

and here is the db file:

```
// db_functions
function selectUserByEmail (email){
    client.query("select * from users where email = ?", email, function(err,rows){
        if(err) { throw err; }
        return rows;
    });
}
module.exports.selectUserByEmail = selectUserByEmail;
```

How can I solve this ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't work (and probably is not working) at all. `db.selectUserByEmail('levon')` is most likely asynchronous and, also likely, returns `undefined`, so it's not surprising that you get `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error.

The question is, why don't you get it in the first case? It's really simple: you are (again, likely) inside a `try..catch` block. Some frameworks wrap your code in these, but `process.nextTick` calls provided function later, so `try..catch` has no effect.

Comment: You are right ... the first case also works intermittently; I'll modify my question; must be because of the asynchronous nature. All I was trying was to separate all the mysql queries/functions to a different file. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: That is a basic `return from asynchronous function` issue. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950984/return-value-from-asynchronous-function-in-nodejs